# SQL Command Not Properly Ended in Oracle - Problems updating table values using joins

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I'm trying to update the sales price of items that are being supplied only by suppliers in DC by 10%, but for some reason, sqlplus is giving me a hard time.

```
update supply
set sprice=(1.1*SPRICE)
FROM SUPPLY
JOIN Supplier on SUPPLIER.SID=SUPPLY.SID
WHERE SUPPLIER.CITY='DC';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That join syntax is not valid in Oracle when using UPDATE. Try this

```
UPDATE SUPPLY
set sprice=(1.1*SPRICE)    
WHERE SUPPLY.SID IN (SELECT SID FROM Supplier WHERE Supplier.CITY='DC');
```

Comment: @RamuDou If my solution helped you, please mark my solution as answer.